# Rake aborted even after completely running migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake

When I generate a new migration, and check by going both up and down, I get 'rake aborted!' at last when I go down, although it runs all the migrations. And there is no problem while going up the migration, everything is smooth. Can anybody tell me why is it happening?

```
 $ rake db:migrate VERSION= 20140217090240
==  CreateSections: reverting =================================================
-- drop_table(:sections)    -> 0.0050s
==  CreateSections: reverted (0.0060s) ========================================

==  CreatePages: reverting ====================================================
-- drop_table(:pages)    -> 0.0030s
==  CreatePages: reverted (0.0040s) ===========================================

==  CreateSubjects: reverting =================================================
-- drop_table(:subjects)    -> 0.0030s
==  CreateSubjects: reverted (0.0230s) ========================================

==  AlterUsers: reverting =====================================================
-- remove_index("admin_users", "username")    -> 0.0180s
-- rename_column("admin_users", "hashed_password", "password")    -> 0.0160s
-- change_column("admin_users", "email", :string, {:default=>"", :null=>false})    -> 0.0110s
-- remove_column("admin_users", "username")    -> 0.0110s
-- rename_table("admin_users", "users")    -> 0.0030s
==  AlterUsers: reverted (0.0680s) ============================================

==  CreateUsers: reverting ====================================================
-- drop_table(:users)    -> 0.0040s
==  CreateUsers: reverted (0.0040s) ===========================================

rake aborted! Don't know how to build task '20140217090240'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string "first_name", :limit => 25
      t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
      t.string "email", :default => "", :null => false
      t.string "password", :limit => 40     
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Comment: paste your error plez.

Comment: It's unclear. please provides some useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Use

To up the migration run

```
  rake db:migrate:up VERSION=version number of migration
```

And for down the migration run

```
 rake db:migrate:down VERSION=version number of migration
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'CreateUsers' migration file contain error. Please observe the user creation file first. It may have some dependency like you add certain user role in the create migration but role table not created before the user table. If you paste the 'CreateUsers' migration file somewhere then paste here the link, it will be easy to find out the issue.

Comment: i have pasted the CreateUsers class above. I don't see anything wrong with it. Can you spot anything?

Comment: Please check in up migration. is there any space between ':' and 'users' like create_table :users

Comment: please see '20140217090240' migration no. is it create user migration file no?  Or you can run by rake db:migrate --trace

Comment: please run all migration by using  rake db:migrate or just rake db:migrate:up VERSION=version_number_of_migration